# File Format for Saving Video with alpha channel in iOS

Tags: ios, avfoundation, video-processing, alpha

I am using AVFoundation to create a video and have added in an effect to clip the video so there is a clear background. What file format should I save this as to preserve the transparency in my iOS app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AVAnimator](http://www.modejong.com/AVAnimator/index.html) is a library with which you can display video with an alpha channel on iOS, it is however not free to use for commercial products.

I don't think it's natively possible.

Comment: Pieter is correct that alpha channel is not possible using the native h.264 features provided with iOS. You could simple use a series of PNG images with alpha channels in them, that would be "free" but your app download would be bloated because a series of PNG images is not space effective in terms of the download size. If quality is not a concern, then there is a low quality green screen effect in GPUImage. AVAnimator (my library) is the highest quality option, but you do have to actually pay to use it in a commercial product. Lots of options available.