# AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool with transparent videolayer

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am making a video composition with graphics on top and behind the video layer. The problem is I cannot set the video layer background color to clear(transparent) it displays always black background color. I would like to show some graphics behind it. Here is the code. I moved the videolayer by -200px just to make sure that the graphics behind it is being shown. How can I set the videolayer to display transparent background?

```
var backLayer = new CALayer
{
    Contents = s.CGImage,
    BackgroundColor = UIColor.White.CGColor,
    Bounds = new CGRect(0, 0, size.Width, size.Height),
    Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, size.Width, size.Height),
    Hidden = false
};

var animationLayer = new CALayer { Contents = s.CGImage };
animationLayer.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear.CGColor;
animationLayer.Bounds = new CGRect(size.Width - 100, 50, 50, 50);
animationLayer.Frame = new CGRect(size.Width - 100, 50, 50, 50);
animationLayer.Hidden = false;

var videoLayer = new CALayer();
videoLayer.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear.CGColor;
videoLayer.ShadowColor = UIColor.Clear.CGColor;
videoLayer.BorderColor = UIColor.Clear.CGColor;
videoLayer.Frame = new CGRect(0, -200, size.Width, size.Height);
videoLayer.Bounds = new CGRect(0, -200, size.Width, size.Height);

parentLayer.AddSublayer(backLayer);
parentLayer.AddSublayer(videoLayer);
parentLayer.AddSublayer(animationLayer);
parentLayer.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear.CGColor;

videoComposition.AnimationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool.FromLayer(videoLayer, parentLayer);
```

Comment: You need to create another video (either as an additional channel in your h.264 file or a separate file) that is an alpha-channel representation of the movie and use that as a transparency layer. This can also be done in 'real-time' using a single video that contains a 'green-screen' / 'chroma-key' color via OpenGL ES(GPUImage provides a method for doing it this way, source @ https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However it's a bit tricky because the videolayer contains dynamically added video assets that are scaled down and played simultaneously. So it could contain 1-5 video assets scaled down accordingly. I want to display e.g. white background or an image behind these video assets. It's strange that I can't just simply set the videolayer background color to clear or at least change the color to white instead of black.

Comment: Would love to hear if you find another way... not sure if iOS 9.x added anything to do this... I had to do it with iOS 7/8 support and GPUImage was the solution at that time as the client did not want to encode an alpha channel...

Comment: You need a real alpha channel, there is no way to fake it. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28276523/763355

Comment: I solved it by adding a white image on top of the videolayer with transparent holes were the video is displayed and it worked like a charm :)